# Unable to create bibliography using TexStudio, Biblatex and JabRef

Tags: biblatex, texstudio, jabref

Using TeXstudio I try to create a file with a Bibliography, created in JabRef. Instead of a properly result, I always get the Bibtexkeys shown in fat print and with no bibliography at the end.

Running biber.exe manually by the GUI before compilation somestimes works (I can try it several times after another without changing anything in between with different results.

Short working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper] {article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

\begin{document}
Allia \cite{Equit2015} est \cite{Bohnsack2000} omnis

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Adding `\nocite{*}` does not change the result either

Using

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
]{biblatex}
```

instead of the short Code, I used, does not change the result.

I always get the following error messages:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 20.10) The top-level auxiliary 
file: texstudio_ojuMPj.aux I found no \citation commands---while 
reading file texstudio_ojuMPj.aux I found no \bibdata command---while 
reading file texstudio_ojuMPj.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while
reading file texstudio_ojuMPj.aux (There were 3 error messages)
```

Testfile.bib

```
 % Encoding: UTF-8

@Book{Bohnsack2000,
  editor    = {Bohnsack, Ralf [Verfasser/in]},
  publisher = {Leske + Budrich},
  title     = {Rekonstruktive Sozialforschung: Einführung in Methodologie und Praxis qualitativer Forschung},
  year      = {2000},
  address   = {Opladen},
  edition   = {4., durchges. Aufl.},
  isbn      = {3-8100-2759-6},
  note      = {Literaturverz. S. 249 - 274},
  series    = {Lehrtexte},
  keywords  = {Qualitative Sozialforschung},
  language  = {Deutsch},
  pages     = {278 Seiten},
}


@Book{Equit2015,
  editor    = {Equit, Claudia [Herausgeber/in]},
  publisher = {Beltz Juventa},
  title     = {Handbuch Grounded Theory: von der Methodologie zur Forschungspraxis},
  year      = {2015},
  address   = {Weinheim, Bergstr},
  isbn      = {978-3-7799-3296-3},
  note      = {ZLB: Amerika-Gedenkbibliothek (AGB)},
  language  = {Deutsch},
  pages     = {511 Seiten},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

Comment: Your document loads `biblatex`, so you need to compile it with Biber and not with BibTeX. A full compile cycle would be LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help with making your editor run Biber instead of BibTeX.

Comment: The `editor = {Bohnsack, Ralf [Verfasser/in]},` in `Bohnsack2000` should just be `author = {Bohnsack, Ralf}` and `editor = {Equit, Claudia [Herausgeber/in]},` in `Equit2015` should just be `editor = {Equit, Claudia},`. Name fields like `editor` should only ever contain a list of names and never additional designations such as *Herausgeberin* or *Verfasserin*.

Comment: Not really relevant to your problem, but the `language` field should ideally contain a language key known to `biblatex`. In case your work is in German `language = {german},` (or equivalently `language = {langgerman},`) is much better than `language = {Deutsch},`. The total page number of a book should be in the `pagetotal` field and not in the `pages` field. Hence, `pages = {278 Seiten},` should be `pagetotal = {278},` (and similarly for `Equit2015`).

Answer (score 1):

You're running BibTeX as backend while you declare in your .tex file that you are going to use biber. Most likely this is because BibTeX is configured as your standard bibliography tool in TeXstudio. To change this to biber, go to: Option -> Configure TeXstudio -> Build. There, change the "Default Bibliography Tool" to `txs:///biber`. That should ensure that TeXstudio will run biber by default to compile the bibliography. If you ever switch back to using BibTeX as backend again, you need to change this back to `txs:///bibtex`

Comment: That was it! Also, after excluding the line "\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}" I got rid of another annoying error message and no everything works. Thank you! (Cannot mark you answer as "useful" due to my low reputation on this board.)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. You can still "accept" an answer even if you cannot "up vote" it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to tell TexStudio that you want to use biber is to add the magic comment "%! BIB TS-program = biber" to your .tex file.

Example:

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = pt_BR
% !TeX root = fichamento.tex
% !BIB TS-program = biber
```